# Maintaining South migrations on Django forks

Tags: django, django-models, merge, django-south, rebase

I'm working on a pretty complex Django project (50+ models) with some complicated logic (lots of different workflows, views, signals, APIs, background tasks etc.). Let's call this `project-base`. Currently using Django 1.6 + South migrations and quite a few other 3rd party apps.

Now, one of the requirements is to create a fork of this project that will add some fields/models here and there and some extra logic on top of that. Let's call this `project-fork`. Most of the extra work will be on top of the existing models, but there will also be a few new ones.

As `project-base` continues to be developed, we want these features to also get into `project-fork` (much like a rebase/merge in git-land). The extra changes in `project-fork` will not be merged back into `project-base`.

What could be the best possible way to accomplish this? Here are some of my ideas:

1. Use South merges in `project-fork` to keep it up-to-date with latest changes from `project-base`, as explained [here](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part5.html#team-workflow). Use signals and any other means necessarry to keep the new logic from `project-fork` as loosely coupled as possible to avoid any potential conflicts.
2. Do not modify ANY of the original `project-base` models and instead create new models in different apps that reference the old models (i.e. using `OneToOneField`). Extra logic could end up in the old and/or new apps.
3. *your idea here please :)*

I would go with option 1 as it seems less complicated as a whole, but might expose a greater risk. Here's how I would see it happening:

Migrations on `project-base`:

- 0001_project_base_one
- 0002_project_base_two
- 0003_project_base_three

Migrations on `project-fork`:

- 0001_project_base_one
- 0002_project_fork_one

After merge, the migrations would look like this:

- 0001_project_base_one
- 0002_project_base_two
- 0002_project_fork_one
- 0003_project_base_three
- 0004_project_fork_merge_noop *(added to merge in changes from both projects)*

Are there any pitfalls using this approach? Is there a better way?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Official South workflow:

The official South recommendation is to try with the `--merge` flag: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part5.html#team-workflow

This obviously won't work in all cases, from my experience it works in most though.

**Pitfalls:**

- Multiple changes to the same model can still break
- Duplicate changes can break things

The "better" way is usually to avoid simultaneous changes to the same models, the easiest way to do this is by reducing the error-window as much as possible.

### My personal workflows in these cases:

**With small forks where the model changes are obvious from the beginning:**

1. Discus which model changes will need to be done for the fork
2. Apply those changes to both/all branches as fast as possible to avoid conflicts
3. Work on the fork ....
4. Merge the fork which gives no new migrations

**With large forks where the changes are not always obvious and/or will change again:**

1. Do the normal fork and development stuff while trying to stay up to date with the latest master/develop branch as much as possible
2. Before merging back, throw away all **schema**migrations in the fork
3. Merge all changes from the master/develop
4. Recreate all needed schema changes
5. Merge to develop/master